# Teradata auto increment id

Tags: teradata

I've been working with teradata for couple of months.
However cannot understand how correctly create auto-incrementing ID.

Serfing the internet I found the most clear and well-working for me the way to create id column as auto generated:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_emp (
     id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1
                                               INCREMENT BY 1
                                               MINVALUE 0
                                               MAXVALUE 1000000
                                               NO CYCLE),
     Name VARCHAR(20),
     Phone VARCHAR(10));
```

But it seems that exists another way to do the same by adding 'primary index (id)':

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_emp (
         id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1
                                                   INCREMENT BY 1
                                                   MINVALUE 0
                                                   MAXVALUE 1000000
                                                   NO CYCLE),
         Name VARCHAR(20),
         Phone VARCHAR(10)) primary index (id);
```

I am a bit confused. What is actual difference between this 2 queries? What will be the result?

Comment: When no `PRIMARY INDEX` or `PRIMARY KEY` (two different things) clause is specified, then either by default the first column is chosen as Primary Index (in which case there is effectively no difference between the two above) or optionally the table is considered as `NO PRIMARY INDEX` (based on system-wide option setting in dbscontrol).

Comment: If you are creating tables in Teradata, and don't understand at the least what a PI does, then you are missing some very fundamental information.  I'd strongly suggest you work with your DBAs and/or do some serious reading on this.

Comment: I know what is PI. I just did not get what it is in context of teradata.